# Linq to sql Error "Data at the root level is invalid " for nullable xml column

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq-to-sql, dbtype

I have Created a table like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tab1]( 
 [Id] [int] NOT NULL, 
 [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL, 
 [Meta] [xml] NULL, 


CONSTRAINT [PK_tab1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
( 
     [Id] ASC 
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I am doing linq to sql query to fetch a data it throw an error "data at the root level is invalid linq". In further investigation I come to know that the meta column is null in that case. In real it is nullable Do I have to remove the nullable and set some blank root node as default or there is some another way to get rid of the error.

---

My linq Query which throws error

```
     var obj1= (from obj in dbContext.tab1s
  where obj.id== 123
select obj).FirstOrDefault<Tab1>();
```

Comment: Could you provide the Linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under no circumstances will you receive this error if the value of an XML column is `NULL`.

You will, however, receive this error if the field contains malformed XML, as the error suggests.

SQL Server permits you to do this:

```
UPDATE tab1
SET Meta = 'blah'
WHERE id = 123
```

Obviously the string "blah" is invalid XML, but SQL Server still allows it.  Linq to SQL does not, because it will try to actually load that XML into an `XElement`.  If you run the query with this value in the column, you will get exactly the same error, *Data at the root level is invalid*.

In order to fix this error you need to fix the malformed XML that is present in the database.

Comment: Thx Aaonaught, I got my answer

Answer (score 0):

The create has [tab1] but your select has [tab1s]